# Get request rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rubygems

Hi i want to "connect" my "Exemple.html.erb" to an API, in this view i want to show some information that i want from this api adress "https://api.exemple.com"

I have the address api and api key.

So how to do a get request from this api address and show the result in my view.

I tried this code and it's not working:

```
require 'httparty'
url = 'https://api.exemple.com'
headers = {   key1: 'apikey',   key2: 'mykeynumber' }
response = HTTParty.get(url, headers: headers) 
puts response.body
```

Comment: So, what is the error?

Comment: Just a blank page.

Comment: I'm afraid, without a reproducible example we can't help you much. HTTParty works. The error must be that you incorrectly set up the request, not the way the  site expects it.

Comment: `puts` is not going to print the output to the page, but rather the console. If you want this data on the page body, you'll need to use `ERB` or another template lang to display from the `response` variable.

Comment: Ok let's say you are seeing blank page as what you said, the API still throw a response code. So, what is the response code did you received?

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you are using erb and want to print inside using Ruby code, you have to wrap any Ruby code with <%= %>, assuming this code you have is in file you mentioned you could try:

*.rb file:*

```
require 'httparty'
url = 'https://api.exemple.com'
headers = {   key1: 'apikey',   key2: 'mykeynumber' }
@response = HTTParty.get(url, headers: headers)
```

*.erb file:*

```
<%= @response.body %>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but i' tried this but i have always a blank page :/

Comment: Always the same error **undefined method `body' for nil:NilClass**

Comment: @Mamiko, did you remember to change your response declaration to have an @ before "response" on the .rb file?  Also, this .rb file should be your controller. Is it?

Comment: Thank you the problem was in my controller